# How to dynamically create an a4j:commandLink in a component renderer?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I'm trying to add some functionality to the **rich:dataTable** by extending its renderer. More specifically, i'd like to render a link in the header column that triggers an ajax call (to trigger an action in a backing bean).

So my fist thought was to modify the dataTable's renderer to instantiate and add an **a4j:commandLink** instance. That does work to some extend, the link does get rendered just fine, however the associated action is not being called, and an added parameter assignemnt is not performed. furthermore i cant really make out what portions of the view are being executed and rendered, it seems the values i set are being ignored (for example if i specify **@all** as a value for those two properties i still get a partial response containing just a tiny fraction of my page).

This is the code i use to create the link:

```
UICommandLink l = (UICommandLink) context.getApplication().createComponent(UICommandLink.COMPONENT_TYPE);
l.setTransient(false);
l.setRender("@all");
l.setExecute("@all");
l.setActionExpression(ULHelper.createMethodExpression("#{orderBy.toggle('"+ sortName + "')}", null, String.class);
l.setParent(uiColumn);
l.getChildren().add(headerFacet);
l.encodeAll(context);
```

**uiColumn** is the UIColumn instance, **headerFacet** is the text that should be rendered within the link.

The link does get displayed correctly, a click on the link triggers an ajax request just fine (no errors in the javascript console) - but i have no idea what happens next on the server side, the action is not getting called, the table is not being re-rendered either.

If i add an ActionListener

```
l.addActionListener(...);
```

or add a parameter instance to the link

```
UIParameter par = (UIParameter) context.getApplication().createComponent(UIParameter.COMPONENT_TYPE);
par.setValue(sortName);
par.setAssignToExpression(ULHelper.createValueExpression("#{bean.text}", String.class));
l.getChildren().add(par);
```

it makes no difference, neither of the two are executed.

I suspect it has something to do with state saving, that the a4j:commandLink does not get saved and therefore the 2nd request does not find that link (and therefore the listener, parameter etc...) to work with, but i have no idea how to persist (and restore) the state of the link.

Answer (score 0):

Just sample from working sources, which may be helpful:

```
import org.ajax4jsf.component.html.HtmlAjaxCommandLink;

    public UIComponent ajaxLink(...) {
        HtmlAjaxCommandLink ajaxLink = new HtmlAjaxCommandLink();
        ajaxLink.setId(...);
        ajaxLink.setValue(...);
        ajaxLink.setAjaxSingle(true);
        ajaxLink.setOncomplete(...some js func..);
        ajaxLink.setReRender(...);
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        MethodExpression actionListenerExpression = context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createMethodExpression(context.getELContext(), "#{someSeamComponent.someAction}", null, new Class[]{ActionEvent.class});
        MethodExpressionActionListener actionListener = new MethodExpressionActionListener(actionListenerExpression);
        ajaxLink.addActionListener(actionListener);
        return ajaxLink;
    }

uiComponent.getChildren().add(ajaxLink(...));
```